# Drawing on a bitmap in Java

Tags: java, swing, bitmap

I am going to do start a project soon and I will have to draw something on a .bmp/.jpg/.ps(any of these) in JFrame.

The pictures will present maps and I will have to generate some dots etc. on them how to do it in Java? Generally how to draw on a picture in Java?

Comment: Why not use an existing map viewer, such as [`JMapViewer`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+user%3Ame+jmapviewer&submit=search).

Comment: Load the image in a BufferedImage and get its Graphics using getGraphics, with it you have access to all the drawing primitives of the Graphics API, and, if you want to do some fancy graphics drawing, you can cast the Graphics object to an instance of a Graphics2D object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) api it has out of the box support for JPEG, PNG, BMP, WBMP & GIF.  You can get TIFF support from the [Advanced Image API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jai-142803.html).

Post script support is a little more tricky, but some PDF renderers can actually accomplish this (I used this approach to convert illustrator image formats).

Comment: Thanks for that!  The javadocs for ImageIO says nothing about the fact that it will always support PNG.  But I searched and found an official tutorial that does explicitly say "the following standard image format plugins : JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP and WBMP are always be present.":  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some tutorials online. Take a look at Listing 14.17 on this site:
[Java ist auch eine Insel](http://openbook.galileodesign.de/javainsel5/javainsel14_008.htm#Rxx747java14008040004CF1F022100)

The code should be readable though the text is german. Hope it helps to make a first step into swing :)


About Bitmaps: I wrote my own Bitmap class to convert a png to a bmp, because the BitmapFactory and co didn't work for me. If you need it and nobody has a better "Java-API"-like solution, you can write me.